# PHP Select sub category of category

Tags: php, sql

I have following database tables structures as :

```
------------------------------------
 main category
        |
        V
| cat_id | cat_name |

-------------------------------------
       sub category
             |
             V
| subCat_id | sub_catName | cat_id |    **cat_id is FK 

----------------------------------------
                product
                   |
                   V 
| pro_id | pro_name | pro_imgpro | price |

----------------------------------------------

 product_category
       |
       V
| subCat_id | pro_id |             **both are FK 

------------------------------------------------
```

I'm trying to display the products based on the subcategory 
what is the correct sql syntax for this

Comment: This is a nice start to a question but you're missing [some important things](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Well..You are really asking for ready made code but let's give it a shot..!

Here is exactly how you can do this through `PHP` approach :

**ACCORDING TO YOUR DATABASE STRUCTURE :**

**Note :** This code is for an example which will grab your whole products which belongs to a specific sub category.

**Theoritical Explanation :** You will need to grab the item's `pro_id` (plural) of all products which belongs to a specific sub category so like this way you will get only the specific products which only belongs to that specific sub category next then you will use the product id's to grab the product's all other details.

Here is exactly how you will be doing it through `PHP` :

```
<?php
include("config.php"); // Your SQL Connection
$sub_category_id = "234"; // Your Sub Category ID Here
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT pro_id FROM product_category WHERE subCat_id='$sub_category_id'");
$pro_ids = array();
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  $pro_ids[] = $rows;
}
for ($i=0;$i<=count($pro_ids);$i++) {
$pro_id_db = $pro_ids[$i]["pro_id"];
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM product WHERE pro_id='$pro_id_db'");
$product = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
echo "Product ID : ".$product["pro_id"]."</br>";
echo "Product Name : ".$product["pro_name"]."</br>";
echo "Product IMGPRO : ".$product["pro_imgpro"]."</br>";
echo "Product Price : ".$product["price"]."</br>";
echo "</br></br></br>";
}
?>
```